# Getting Index Out of Bounds Error When Trying to add Elements to a new 2D arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, graph, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement the graph ADT in java, and for some reason even though I can add vertices to my 1D arraylist without issue, however  I keep getting "Index 0 out of bounds for length 0" for my 2D arraylist of edges. I'm wondering if I'm using the arraylist incorrectly, or there's a problem at another point in my program (like the function to insert an edge).

[image: Error]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GraphADT
{
    // constructor, takes in 1D arraylist of vertices, and 2D list of edges
    public GraphADT(ArrayList<Integer> Vert, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Edges)
    {
        this.V = Vert;
        this.E = Edges;
        this.adj = new boolean[V.size()][V.size()];
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> V;
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> E;

    public boolean[][] adj; // adjacency matrix

    // increment v, w to make sure the edge doesn't already exist
    // otherwise set the connection to be true

    // return list of vertices
    public ArrayList<Integer> vertices()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> vertList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= V.size(); i++)
        {
            int vert = V.get(i);
            vertList.add(vert);
        }
        return vertList;
    }

    public int insertVertex(int x)
    {
        this.V.add(x);
        return x;
    }

    public void removeVertex(int y)
    {

        // removes all adjacency matrix connections
        // to the vertex that needs to be deleted
        for (int i = 0; i < adj.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < adj.length; j++)
                if (i == y || j == y)
                {
                    adj[i][j] = false;
                }
        }

        // Remove vertex from the vertex List.
        this.V.remove(y);

    }

    public void insertEdge(int v, int w)
    {

        if (!adj[v][w])
        {
            v++;
            w++;

        } else
        {
            adj[v][w] = true;
            adj[w][v] = true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> V = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        V.add(1);
        V.add(2);
        V.add(3);
        V.add(4);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> E = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        // getting edge indices and adding pairs to them
        E.get(0).add(1, 3);
        E.get(1).add(1, 1);
        E.get(2).add(1, 2);
        E.get(3).add(3, 4);

        GraphADT G = new GraphADT(V, E);

        G.insertVertex(5);
        G.insertVertex(6);
        G.insertVertex(7);

        G.insertEdge(2, 4);
    }

}
```

and if I try to use new to create space for the 0th row I still get an error

[image]

Comment: Check please how  `add` method works in case of 2 params. You try to insert to ArrayList with size 0 element on 1st position. This is why your code crush

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a "Set" data structure for the edges? Using ArrayLists nested into ArrayLists seems way too complicated.

But your Error Is clearly coming from line 87 --> You try to reference an element at index 0, but there is no element yet.

Comment: I'm considering using a set, although I've never used one before which is why I used an array list. I understand that the error is at line 87, but the problem is that I don't know how to add something to the list without first referencing some type of index. I can't just use add() with the 2D arraylist for some reason. If I just use add i get a compile time error "The method add(int, ArrayList<Integer>) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)".

Comment: Thats correct. In an ArrayList you can always just add another element, independent from the index. The index is therefore simply incrementing automatically after every added element. After adding an element you can also reference it by using the get() method. For this use case I recommend looking into the data structure "HashSet", which can simply store Key Value pairs. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm planning on using a hashmap for the edge list, do you think this would also work? or should i use a hash set.